# JsonInclude How to ignore default value boolean only when is not assigned

Tags: spring, rest, jackson

when I use Include.NON_NULL, the error response is wrong and if I use Include.NON_DEFAULT, the response with status 200 is wrong

This is what I'm looking for:

Status: 200 OK

```
{
        "adultMovie": false,
        "backdropPathMovie": "/2U3hyiVzzhYzS6j9fcdVW4mO4Uk.jpg",
        "originalLanguageMovie": "en",
        "originalTitleMovie": "Fire"
}
```

Status: 400

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "typeId": "FIELD_VALIDATION_ERRORS",
            "field": "idMovie",
            "message": "Invalid value of `fff` provided"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is what I tried so far:
My model:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Movie implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3515253168981789136L;

    private boolean adultMovie;

    private String backdropPathMovie;

    private String originalLanguageMovie;

    private String originalTitleMovie;

    private Set<Error> errors;
}
```

Status: 200 OK

```
{
    "adultMovie": false,
    "backdropPathMovie": "/2U3hyiVzzhYzS6j9fcdVW4mO4Uk.jpg",
    "originalLanguageMovie": "en",
    "originalTitleMovie": "Fire"
}
```

Status: 400. Validation error

```
{
        "adultMovie": false, // It shouldn't show up
        "errors": [
            {
                "typeId": "FIELD_VALIDATION_ERRORS",
                "field": "idMovie",
                "message": "Invalid value of `513f` provided"
            }
        ]
}
```

If I try:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT)
public class Movie implements Serializable {
```

Status: 200 OK

```
{
        "backdropPathMovie": "/2U3hyiVzzhYzS6j9fcdVW4mO4Uk.jpg",
        "originalLanguageMovie": "en",
        "originalTitleMovie": "Fire"
} // Here should show up "adultMovie": false, as this field is set as false.
```

Status: 400. Validation error

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "typeId": "FIELD_VALIDATION_ERRORS",
            "field": "idMovie",
            "message": "Invalid value of `fff` provided"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not clear;
the question subject is the "subject" of the question,
it is not the text of the question.

Source of your problem: You must learn how to count.

Description:
A `boolean` may contain exactly two values; true and false.
Based on my imagination of what you wanted to ask,
it appears that you want something that contains three values;
true, false, and not-set.

Use `Boolean` as the type of the `adultMovie` field.
`Boolean` is a reference type;
therefore it can have three values;
Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.FALSE, and null.

In concert with the `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` annotation,
a null value for `adultMovie` will result in JSON that does not contain the "adultMovie" entry.

Comment: Sorry for the question subject. Effectively I wanted something with 3 possible values and it worked with Boolean as you mentioned. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5):

Instead on boolean you can use Boolean like below. boolean is having values either true or false and default value is false if not set. Therefore with @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT) even though you have set false value manually it will assume it's default value and will ignore this value even though you required this in response. On the other hand Boolean is having three values like true, false and null. So if you have set it to false it will also consider in in response. Only if you set to null it will not include in response.

private Boolean adultMovie;